# beginner: c++ code: strings are being duplicated when printed

Tags: string, for-loop, vector

so i coded a program where you enter "n" amount of strings. Porgram prints first and last string by alphabet order, then prints the rest of them (no alphabet order for the rest)

example, a user enters

```
ab 
cd 
ef 
gh
```

Program should pirnt:

```
ab 
gh 
cd 
ef
```

This part above works fine in my code, the problem comes when you enter 2 times a same string, it will print them both, which should not happen... it should skip the duplicates and do its original job.

for example if I enter in my code:

```
ab 
cd 
ef 
gh 
ab
```

Program will print two times ab, etc.

```
ab 
ab 
cd 
ef 
gh
```

This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
cout<<"Enter a number of words: ";
int n;
cin>>n;

vector<string> v;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    string temp;
    cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<". word: ";
    cin>>temp;
    v.push_back(temp);
}
if(v[0][0]<v[n-1][0])cout<<v[0]<<endl<<v[n-1];
else cout<<v[n-1]<<endl<<v[0];

cout<<endl;
for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++){
    cout<<v[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

It's probably an easy fix, but not for me.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the input part and instead programatically insert the data to get closer to a minimal example. That said, at what point exactly does the program go wrong? Learn to use a debugger or use output statements to find that point. Then, the error is on the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want multiple elements in your array you should check every time a string is going to be added if it's already present (in a loop, comparing with all the other strings) or you can change the container from a `vector` to another which guarantees uniqueness, like [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Using a vector you can change your code like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a number of words: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<string> v;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ) {
        string temp;
        cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << ". word: ";
        cin >> temp;

        // loop through the vector searching for temp
        int j = 0;
        while ( j < v.size()  &&  v[j] != temp ) 
            ++j;

        // add temp if it isn't already present
        if ( j == v.size() ) {
            v.push_back(temp);
            ++i;
        }
        else 
            cout << temp << " is already present\n";
    }

    // use the real size of the vector
    int last = v.size() - 1;
    if ( v[0][0] < v[last][0] )
        cout << v[0] << endl << v[last];
    else
        cout << v[last] <<endl <<v[0];

    cout << endl;
    for ( int i = 1; i < last; i++ ){
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @noobcoder What do you mean? My answer is supposed to help solving the problem stated in your question. Try my code and see if it works as you expected. You don't have to change your question, if my answer helps and you find it useful you can then upvote or [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.

Comment: I tried, program crashed, I have the code I just wanted someone to fix it and explain what they done.

Comment: @noobcoder try now. In case of duplicates you can ask for another word or not, but I forgot to add the code for calculate the real size of the vector after the input

Comment: even though program should delete the duplicates after entered and continue it's original job, you've done a nice thing here thanks.